# Getting Error for doesn't have default value in Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `day_schedules` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-03-13 06:56:39, 2017-03-13 06:56:39))

Controller:

```
if(isset($eventId)){
    //dd($eventId);
    for($i=0; $i<$days;$i++){
        $request->request->add(['user_id'=>$userid]);
        $request->request->add(['event_id'=>$eventId]);
        $dayPostData = Day::create($request->except(['_token', 'submit', 'title','description','firstDate','secondDate', 'days','location','tags','event-img','event_img','sch-e','sch-s','sch-title','sch-desc']));
        $dayId=$dayPostData->id;
        //dd($dayId);
        $countSchedules=count($arr[$i]);
        //$scheduleData = DaySchedule::firstOrNew(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
        for ($j=0;  $j < $countSchedules; $j++){
            //dd($eventId);
            $request->request->add(['user_id'=>$userid]);
            $request->request->add(['event_id'=>$eventId]);
            $request->request->add(['day_id'=>$dayId]);
            $scheduleData = DaySchedule::create([$request->except(['_token', 'submit', 'title','description','firstDate','secondDate' ,'days','location','tags','event-img','event_img'])]);

        }

    }

}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `day_schedules` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `event_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `day_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `time_s` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `time_e` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `sch_title` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `sch_desc` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_dayschedules_users` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `FK_dayschedules_events` (`event_id`),
    INDEX `FK_dayschedules_days` (`day_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_dayschedules_days` FOREIGN KEY (`day_id`) REFERENCES `days` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_dayschedules_events` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_dayschedules_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: What do you get if you `dd($request->except(...))`  for the `DaySchedule::create()` (change the `...` for the actual params) method.

Comment: its return User id and Event id.

Comment: Have you got `user_id` in the fillable array for that model?

Comment: @RossWilson no.. not yet

Comment: That is probably the issue.

Comment: how to get it?? please can u explain?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is most likely in STRICT mode. Try running SET GLOBAL sql_mode='' or edit your my.cnf to make sure you aren't setting STRICT_ALL_TABLES or the like.

in your phpmyadmin run SELECT @sql_mode in your database sql check sql_mode